# drupal colorful menu

Tags: drupal, menu

how do I create colorful menu just like the www.io1.biz in drupal 7?
is there any module or sth like that or I have to code?
by the way I'm using omega html5 theme at the moment.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try wiht [Mega menu](http://drupal.org/project/megamenu). you can customize the css to achieve the same.

> > **Features**
>
> 1. Turns a Drupal menu into a Mega Menu Creates javascript events on menu open/close for interactive possibilities.
> 2. Solves the "diagonal problem" (menus do not immediately disappear
>      when the mouse  moves away from the parent menu item, or moves
>      between panes)